# How to use Pandas extractall()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few million event logs stored in Panda dataframe. One column, called `data`, stores the event log details. Here's one example:

```
SubjectUserName=XXXX, SubjectDomainName=XX, TargetUserName=XXXX, TargetDomainName=XX.LOCAL, TargetServerName=XXXX.xx.local, TargetInfo=exchangeMDB/XXXX.xx.local, ProcessName=C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe
```

I have millions of rows that have different `key=value` pairs depending on the event that was captured.

What I'm after is extracting all the keys and counting how many times each key was seen across the entire dataset. For example:

```
item, count
SubjectUserName, 1000
TargetServerName, 2000
...
```

My code looks like this:

```
events = eventlogs()
items = events['data'].str.findall('([^ =]+)=')
items = items.value_counts()
return items
```

I'm getting the following error: `AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 25 columns`.

What's the proper way of using extractall() or another method in this case?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

- Alexander.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by `,` and [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for one column `df` and then split by `=`. Last [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
print (df)
                                                data
0  SubjectUserName=XXXX, SubjectDomainName=XX, Ta...
1  SubjectUserName=XXXX, SubjectDomainName=XX, Ta...

df = df.data.str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().to_frame('data')
splitted = df.data.str.split('=', expand=True)
splitted.columns = ['key','val']
print (splitted)
                   key                               val
0 0    SubjectUserName                              XXXX
  1  SubjectDomainName                                XX
  2     TargetUserName                              XXXX
  3   TargetDomainName                          XX.LOCAL
  4   TargetServerName                     XXXX.xx.local
  5         TargetInfo         exchangeMDB/XXXX.xx.local
  6        ProcessName  C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe
1 0    SubjectUserName                              XXXX
  1  SubjectDomainName                                XX
  2     TargetUserName                              XXXX
  3   TargetDomainName                          XX.LOCAL
  4   TargetServerName                     XXXX.xx.local
  5         TargetInfo         exchangeMDB/XXXX.xx.local
  6        ProcessName  C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe
```

---

```
items = splitted.key.value_counts().reset_index()
items.columns = ['item','count']
print (items)
                item  count
0    SubjectUserName      2
1   TargetServerName      2
2        ProcessName      2
3   TargetDomainName      2
4  SubjectDomainName      2
5     TargetUserName      2
6         TargetInfo      2
```

Another faster solution if no `NaN` values in `data` column with `DataFrame` constructor and `list comprehension`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ x.split(', ') for x in df['data'].values.tolist()])
       .stack()
       .to_frame('data')
print (df)
                                             data
0 0                          SubjectUserName=XXXX
  1                          SubjectDomainName=XX
  2                           TargetUserName=XXXX
  3                     TargetDomainName=XX.LOCAL
  4                TargetServerName=XXXX.xx.local
  5          TargetInfo=exchangeMDB/XXXX.xx.local
  6  ProcessName=C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe
1 0                          SubjectUserName=XXXX
  1                          SubjectDomainName=XX
  2                           TargetUserName=XXXX
  3                     TargetDomainName=XX.LOCAL
  4                TargetServerName=XXXX.xx.local
  5          TargetInfo=exchangeMDB/XXXX.xx.local
  6  ProcessName=C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe

splitted = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('=') for x in df['data'].values.tolist()])
splitted.columns = ['key','val']

items = splitted.key.value_counts().reset_index()
items.columns = ['item','count']
print (items)
                item  count
0    SubjectUserName      2
1   TargetServerName      2
2        ProcessName      2
3   TargetDomainName      2
4  SubjectDomainName      2
5     TargetUserName      2
6         TargetInfo      2
```